# Why disposing NetworkStream disconnects client

Tags: c#, using, networkstream, disconnect

When the following bare bones code is sending or receiving data, the client becomes disconnected.

It was my understanding that a using block disposes the object it creates, ie the NetworkStream object, but why does the TcpClient Socket disconnect?

The console output is...
True
False

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.Title = "Client";

            Process p = Process.Start(@"C:\Users\Teddy\Documents\visual studio 2015\code\TesyingNetworkStream\Server\bin\Debug\server.exe");
            Thread.Sleep(1000);

            IPEndPoint EP = new IPEndPoint(
                    IPAddress.Parse("192.168.1.10"), 4000
                    );

            TcpClient cli = new TcpClient();
            cli.Connect(EP);

            UseClient(cli);

            Console.ReadLine();
            p.Kill();
            p.Close();
        }

        private static void UseClient(TcpClient cli)
        {
            using (NetworkStream ns = cli.GetStream())
            {
                Console.WriteLine(cli.Connected);//True
            }
            Console.WriteLine(cli.Connected);//False
        }
    }
```

Here is server code if it matters.

```
class Program2
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.Title = "Server";

            TcpListener lis = new TcpListener(
                new IPEndPoint(
                    IPAddress.Any, 4000
                    ));

            lis.Start();

            lis.AcceptTcpClient();

            while (true)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(10);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's the `GetStream()` function implementation (from [.NET framework source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com)):

```
public NetworkStream GetStream() {
    if (m_CleanedUp){
        throw new ObjectDisposedException(this.GetType().FullName);
    }
    if (!Client.Connected) {
        throw new InvalidOperationException(SR.GetString(SR.net_notconnected));
    }
    if (m_DataStream == null) {
        m_DataStream = new NetworkStream(Client, true);
    }
    return m_DataStream;
}
```

Note the `true` in the call to the `NetworkStream` constructor. This is the `ownsSocket` parameter. From [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.networkstream.-ctor):

> If the value of `ownsSocket` parameter is `true`, the NetworkStream takes
> ownership of the underlying Socket, and calling the `Close` method also
> closes the underlying Socket.

`NetworkStream`'s `Dispose` implementation `Close`'s the stream, which then closes the socket.

Answer (score 2):

It is because `cli.GetStream();` does not create a new stream every time you call it, there is a single stream for the connection and every call to `cli.GetStream();` returns the same stream object. When you dispose of that shared stream that signals to the TcpClient you are done and it marks the TcpClient disconnected.